# "return false;" in the event handler breaks page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery function that collapses an ol and it is working great...

The last line **"return false"** is causing a problem.   I need that single line to have the ol collapse correctly.   However, including that line causes all other buttons / **links on my page to stop working**.   You can click them, but they don't take you anywhere!

I comment that **single line** out, and my ol collapse doesn't work, but the button links work!

I can't figure it out.  I have narrowed it down to that single line!  Any suggestions?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li').click(function () {
                $(this).children('ol').slideToggle();

                var myDiv = $('.region-sidebar-first .block-menu ul.menu').children('li').children('a');

                if (myDiv.hasClass('active')) {
                    myDiv.hide();
                }

                if ($(this).children('.collapse').is(':visible')) {
                   // alert('collapse');
                    $(this).children('.expand').css("display", "block")
                    $(this).children('.collapse').css("display", "none")
                }
                else {
                   // alert('open');
                    $(this).children('.expand').css("display", "none")
                    $(this).children('.collapse').css("display", "block")
                }

                return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: What's your reason for returning false?

Comment: Please cache $(this) it's hurting my eyes.